# Can I swap OS SD cards among Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, sd-card

I've got several raspberry pi computers. They are the same hardware revisions.

If I swap the SD cards amongst them, will the OSes bootup successfully with their respective OS's and software or will the different hardware IDs throw unrecoverable errors (MAC address, ect...) ? They are all standard installations of wheezy raspbian w/ some custom monitoring software on top.

I cannot test this functionality since these machines are thousands of miles away. I've programmed up replacement SD cards /w new software on my ground spare Pi, but cannot actually verify if these SD Card's OSes will function properly (bootup and make it to init.d and user daemons) upon swapping the SD cards into the equipment in the field.

I'm confident my software, embedded bus address discovery for auxiliary senors, and remote access is sound, but I'm not sure what will happen when the OS boots up on previously unknown PI's hardware IDs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I have multiple sd cards and pis and have no problem with the boot up. I have 40 pis and 30sd cards.